# split values separately from a list of tuples

Tags: python

how to separate each value from a list of tuples using line.split(",")?(python)

```
code > for line in path_list:
           val=line.split(",")
           print val

path_list[ (<__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a2170>, <__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a2290>, <__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a04d0>, <__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a1950>, <__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a1320>, <__main__.wirelessnode instance at 0x19a24d0>)]
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: with a **for** loop, exactly like you did for your path list: `for line in path: for val in line: print val`

Answer (score 1):

`path_list` is a list of tuple.

A `list` like a `tuple` is already an "sequence of items". You can walk using `for in`:

```
for line in path:
    for val in line:
        print val
```

See the [documentation about basic Python data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.htm) for more insights.